# Wakelock alternative, right using - android

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I using Wakelock in my Service, because the Service and the handy must working the whole time. It works very fine, but its drain the batterypower very fast.

Actually my code for the wakelock:

```
    public static PowerManager pm;
    public static PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    wl.acquire();
```

If the Service is closed I do

```
    wl.release();
```

I think it is a way, but not the best. And another question - for what I can use the "My Tag". 
Maybe you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As doc says:

> Device battery life will be significantly affected by the use of this API. Do not acquire PowerManager.WakeLocks unless you really need them, use the minimum levels possible, and be sure to release them as soon as possible.

So, using WakeLock for a long time will definitely drain battery. There is no workaround for that! WakeLocks are used to prevent the phone to go in standby mode, they keep the CPU on! As you can understand, keeping CPU on, causes battery draining.

My suggestion is to acquire the wakelock only when it's needed, and releasing immediatily after! If you can tell us what is your goal, we can help you.

The "MyTag" is used only for debugging stuff. If you get an exception for example, the logcat prints "MyTag" as the WakeLock's name that caused that

Comment: Thank you,
I develop an App which takes pictures and I register some events and Intents from the Android plattform. It is possible that only every hours an event is registered, sometimes every minutes, but if i have registered an event then it must work and the handy must react. Can I use Wakelock in an interval to example i activate it every 15 minutes? The display of device can be off / must be off after a while, the camera must be active. Thank you.

Comment: I have the answer. Have you checked the AlarmManager class? This class can fire events in time. You can set when to fire events, and what to do. You can even make them repeatable. A trick could be: Set the alarm in 15 minutes for example, and when you trigger the event, you acquire the wakelock and so on..

Comment: To example i use the the earphone input, if someone put the earphones in the device i want to do something, for this I use the BroadcastReceiver. But this must work the whole days every minute every hour. Than I set alarms with the AlarmManager class. Maybe i can set an alarm every 15 minutes to wakelock? Or works the handy the wholetime if i set an alarm regulary - to example for every 2 minutes, without using wakelock?

Can I request the wakelock status? Is active or inactive programmatically?

Comment: If you register the receiver to the plug earphones in event, you get your Intent without using WakeLock. You have to use Wakelocks only if you have to do long operations AFTER that.

Comment: Can I request the wakelock status? Is active or inactive programmatically? But maybe ive got the first intent after hours, than the cpu maybe sleep and i doesn't get some information. And what means a long time, after which time the cpu stop? Thank you for the fast response.

Comment: You get the WakeLock status by calling wakelock.isHeld(). If true, it's acquired, false if not. Anyway, even if your phone is in standby since 3 hours, when you plug the earphones you get the Intent so you get the event on your BroadcastReceiver. For long operation I mean like more than 1-2 minutes. Could be useful for downloading large images, movies, or parse large webpage, anything else. But if you want only to trigger the earphone plug in event you just need to register the Receiver. Keep in mind that the onReceive method must finish the execution in 3-4 seconds!

Comment: Ok I unserstand, here some concret questions:
If I use an runnable in my Service or app i can prevent to stop the cpu?

If I use BroadcastIntents the Wakelock is not required, only for long operations after it so i can set the Wakelock after the Broadcast Intent and stop them after the action is complete?

I want to use an runnable for an interval to example every 30 minutes - it is possible that the device got no intent in this time and it do notehing else - can I do that without the Wakelock or maybe stops the cpu?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok I think I understood. If you want to use this runnable, in order to mainatin the CPU on, you must acquire the wakelocks. I suggest you to use the wakelocks inside this runnable. Keep in mind that if the screen is on, wakelocks are useless. So you can acquire them without problems, the main thing is to remember to release them. If you use the runnable without wakelocks and phone goes in standby, the runnable is stopped. To be sure the phone executes the runnable after 30 minutes, you must use the AlarmManager class and its set(int,long,operation) method

Comment: Ok, mostly the screen is off. Maybe that works, what do you think: I only use wakelock after I got an Intent than the programm do his action and than i stop the wakelock. Than I have an runnable that runs every second, i should set with this runnable an Alarm - because this works without wakelock? Or can i set to an simple alarm every minute which prevent the device to turn off the cpu?

Comment: You can set the alarm repeating every minute! You don't have to use the Runnable :)

Comment: Prevent the alarm to stop the cpu? Than I can the Wakelock only at the action, not the whole time. If the alarm makes the cpu alive in which interval must I set this.

Comment: Yes, the alarm wakes the CPU if I am not wrong. There is a FLAG to wake the cpu :)

Comment: Yes, this sounds very good, than i can set every minute some alarm, which increment some variable and thats all. Do you something about the cpu sleep time? I've read something about 30 minutes. Is an alarm with RTC_WAKEUP like alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                  + (time), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), i, intent, 0)); correct?

Comment: I don't know the cpu sleep time, I think it depends on many devices but i'm not sure. Anyway, the RTC_WAKEUP is the right flag! I didn't remember the name. In this case you are activating the Broadcast recevier exactly when (time) has passed from when you call this method, so I think you're right :)